Prove that the graph of $f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ is a smooth manifold
I would like to prove that
$$
A=\{(x,y,z) : z= \frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}, (x,y)\neq 0\}
$$
is a smooth sub-manifold of dimension $2$.
I think it is a direct application of the inverse function theorem on  the map $f(x,y,z)=(x,y,z-\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2})$ where $f : (\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{(0,0)\})\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$.
Attempt :
A simple computation proves that its differential is surjective ($\det(df_{(x,y,z)})\neq 0$) at any point of $A\subset(\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{(0,0)\})\times\mathbb{R}$. Let $(x,y,z)\in A$, by the inverse function theorem, there exists an open set $U$ of $(\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{(0,0)\})\times\mathbb{R}$ such that $f : U\to f(U)$ is a diffeomorphism. Now let $V=U\cap A$, we have that $\tilde{f}=f_{|V}$ is an homeomorphism from $V$ to $\tilde{f}(V)$ where $\tilde{f}(V)$ is now an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}\times\{0\}$ (considering the subspace topology on $A$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}\times\{0\}$) and it admits a smooth extension (i.e. a map $F$ defined on an open set $O\subset(\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{(0,0)\})\times\mathbb{R}$ smooth in the classical sense such that $F_{|V}=\tilde{f}$) trivially given by $f$. The same applies for its inverse $\tilde{f}^{-1}$. Finally, $\mathbb{R}^{2}\times\{0\}$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, denote $p : \mathbb{R}^{2}\times\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ this diffeomorphism. Then $p\circ\tilde{f}$  sends diffeomorphically $V$ an open set of $A$ containing $(x,y,z)$ to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Since $(x,y,z)\in A$ was arbitrary, this shows that $A$ is a smooth sub-manifold of dimension $2$.
Is this seems correct to you ?
Thank you a lot !

Sorry I forgot to mention that the definitions of a smooth manifold, a smooth map and a diffeomorphism that I use are the one used in Milnor’s book.In particular Paul Frost’s answer in this post detailed it Milnor's definition of smooth manifold

Write out your proof in detail, step by step. Your answer is incomplete or wrong if even you k ow that you haven’t verified every assumption of a theorem.

@Deane Thank you for your comment. I followed your advice, let me know if it is still not correct please.

Do you not know in general that the graph of a smooth function is a smooth submanifold?

@TedShifrin I have heard this result but never proved it. I encountered this particular case (that has a very nice graph I have to say) and I thought it would be a good idea to try to prove it and I naturally thought of the inverse function theorem. I updated the title to be clearer.

I do not know what definitions you are using or what you have. I would not use the inverse function theorem. Either (1) The mapping $\pi(x,f(x))=x$ gives a chart on the entire graph (or $\phi(x)=(x,f(x))$ gives a diffeomorphism onto the graph) or (2) by the implicit function theorem the zero-set of $F(x,y)=y-f(x)$ is a submanifold. (Here $x$ and $y$ can be in arbitrary dimensions.)

Thank you for the comment ! I did not think of the implicit function theorem, but the first idea is close to the intuition I tried to translate in my proof. I used the definition of a smooth map between arbitrary subsets of the euclidean space given in Milnor’s book topology from the differentiable viewpoint (and as a consequence his definition of a diffeomorphism between arbitrary subsets of the euclidean space), I will add it to the post it was very ambiguous to not mention it sorry.

What are the definitions of manifold and submanifold you are trying to use?
